# EC ElGamal multiplicatively Homomorphic

Tags: elliptic-curves, homomorphic-encryption, elgamal-encryption

Can we make EC ElGamal have multiplicative homomorphic property?

Comment: If you can find a homomorphism $f$ that maps from the domain multiplicative group to EC group with point addition, allowing efficient calculation both ways, you can. Do you know of such thing?

Comment: No, because you can't multiply one group element with another group element.

Comment: @jeleli, please edit your question to include any attempt or blockage thereof that you yourself have found in trying to do what the question requests us do.